# Proper way to build a compiled alternation list

Tags: python, regex, regex-alternation

I have a series of regex patterns that get grouped into categories.  I'm trying to statically compile them into alternations, but I don't want any special meanings to get lost.

As an example, I'm identifying Raspberry Pi GPIO pins by name.  There are the GPIO pins, 0-27 (coincidentally the same numbers as the BCP nomenclature), the voltage reference pins, and the named-function pins.  Depending upon into which category a particular physical pin falls, assumptions can be made; for example, a voltage-reference pin never has a pull-up status nor a GPIO/BCM number.

So:

```py
_cats = {
    'data': (
        r'gpio\.?([0-9]|[1-3][0-9]|40)',
    ),
    'vref': (
        r'v3_3',
        r'v5'
        r'gnd',
    ),
    'named': (
        r'SDA\.?([01])',
        r'CE\.?0'
        r'CE\.?1',
    ),
}
```

The first thing I want to do is combine all of the patterns into a single compiled alternation so I can check whether an input actually *matches* any of my keys.  For a single string in the first dict, I could simply use:

```py
crx = rx.compile(('\A' + _cats['data'][0] + '\Z'), rx.IGNORECASE)
```

For all of them, I could do something like:

```py
crx = re.compile('|'.join([('\A' + rx + '\Z') for rx in _cats['vref']]), re.IGNORECASE)
```

but this is starting to confuse me.  Each regex term should be `^$` or `\A\Z` bounded, but joining them into alternations and *then* compiling them is giving me issues.

I'm looking for something like Emacs' [`regexp-opt`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegexpOpt) function.

I've tried variations on the theme described, and getting syntax errors, patterns that don't match anything, and patterns that match too much.

*Edit*

Thanks for the comments which helped clarify and solve my main question, but I think the second part got lost somewhere.  Specifically,

Is a compiled regex itself a regular expression, or is it a sort of opaque end-point?  Would this (p-codish) work?

```py
rx_a = re.compile(r'(?:a|1|#)')
rx_b = re.compile(r'(?:[b-z]|[2-9]|@)')
rx_c = re.compile('|'.join([repr(rx_a), repr(rx_b)]))
```

Or something of the sort?

Comment: The original question pointed out that I was using Python, but it was immediatelyt elided by a moderator.  So, Python.  And the backticks were accidentally inserted for formatting, not semantics.

Comment: Thanks, spotted the errors and fixed.

Comment: It's not necessary to say the language in the title, it's in the tags.

Comment: Noted for future reference and behavioural correction, although it seems to cater to people who update multiple fields rather than simply looking for "doing X in Python." {shrug}

Comment: They should search for `[python] doing X`

Comment: Anyway, what is your question? Now that you fixed the typo, your code looks good.

Comment: It would be best to put `(?:...)` around each alternative, in case it contains `|`

Comment: Actually, the groups within regex items, such as `gpio\.?([0-9]|[1-3][0-9]|40)` are actually there in order to be able to extract those portions of the match.  Are those the ones you meant?

Comment: No, I meant when you're joining them together, add `(?:` and `)` around each `rx`. `'\A(?:' + rx + ')\Z'`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve all of your requirements with regex `named groups`.

The syntax is: `(?P<NAME>EXPRESSION)`.

```py
import re

#expressions
DATA  = r'(?P<data>gpio\.?([0-9]|[1-3][0-9]|40))'
VREF  = r'(?P<vref>v3_3|v5|gnd)'
NAMED = r'(?P<named>SDA\.?([01])|CE\.?[01])'

#compiled expression
search = re.compile(fr'{DATA}|{VREF}|{NAMED}').search

#find
if m:=search(YourData):
    print(m.group('data'))
    print(m.group('vref'))
    print(m.group('named'))
```